# Plasma Flow Direction

Tags: plasma-physics

How can plasma flow be directed? I’m having a hard time figuring it out this could be done considering the opposing polarities of the ions and the electrons.

Comment: Your question is too open-ended. Can you start with a specific configuration of an experiment?

Comment: Apply a static electric field orthogonal to a static magnetic field and you will get a flow of both charges orthogonal to both field directions.  It's called the ExB-drift.